# Rails Missing Helper File (application_helpers.rb) / Action Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen this question here several times but I am getting something extra. I install Rails (latest version) and create a new project from my root directory (c:). I made sure all the file names were lowercase. I start the rails server and on the first request for the welcome page I get the 
"Missing helper file rails/helpers/application_helpers.rb" error.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-19 21:07:21 -0500

AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError (Missing helper file helpers/rails/application_helpers.rb):

actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:152:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:149:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:145:in `map!'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:145:in `modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:93:in `modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:109:in `helper'
```

I then request the page again, and I am given the welcome page.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-19 21:08:11 -0500
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
Rendering c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (27.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3690ms (Views: 644.5ms)
```

Baffled by this behaviour I then request the welcome page again and I get this:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-19 21:14:47 -0500

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'index' could not be found for Rails::WelcomeController):

actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
...and so on
```

I don't know what to make of this. I requested the same thing within a span of minutes and received three different results, with no changes made whatsoever. I uninstalled Rails and reinstalled. I've opened three new projects in different file locations with pretty much the same result. I just got my Ruby Silver certification and really want to learn to work with Rails but I can't get past a simple GET request for an index page... I've read all the relative question posts on here and it seems like renaming the directory fixes what issues were present, but not for me.

I'm running Windows 10

Ruby 2.3.3p222

Rails 5.1.1

Comment: Just a small suggestion, if you wish to learn Ruby on Rails, I would suggest you to switch to Ubuntu, otherwise while using gem files, you will get into a problem, of course MacOS is also fine

Comment: can you go to your controllers folder, and click on the WelcomeController and see if there is an action in there called "index"?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. And yes there is an action called "index" in that folder. I ended up fixing the problem, for now... When I had originally installed Ruby I used RailsInstaller, which installed Ruby and Ruby on Rails. I had never worked with Rails when I was learning Ruby so I ended up forgetting it was already on the system. Downloading and installing Rails yet again confused the system into looking for the correct path among several directories. Basically, I uninstalled every instance of Rails and Ruby and started over. For now everything works..

Comment: To follow up on @Hatik important point. Windows was not made for RoR, so save yourself another headache and use Cloud9 IDE for RoR development.